# Auto Sorting Tailwind CSS class in React Native project

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, prettier

We are using Visual Studio Code to develop a react native project using Tailwind CSS with this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twrnc. We had installed Prettier in our vscode and postcss, prettier, prettier-plugin-tailwindcss in our package.json's devDependencies section.

The auto complete function work fine but the auto sorting cannot work.
[twrnc with **style** class Attribute not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni26K.png)
But when we switch the **style** keyword to **class**, it works.[twrnc with **class** class Attribute work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO5Dl.png)

We try to follow the config setting suggestion here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7553#issuecomment-735915659

Here is our VSCode setting json:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "tailwindCSS.classAttributes": ["class", "className", "ngClass", "style"],
  "scss.validate": false,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
  },
  "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always",
  "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
    "tw`([^`]*)", // tw`...`
    "tw=\"([^\"]*)", // <div tw="..." />
    "tw={\"([^\"}]*)", // <div tw={"..."} />
    "tw\\.\\w+`([^`]*)", // tw.xxx`...`
    "tw\\(.*?\\)`([^`]*)" // tw(Component)`...`
  ],
  "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "typescript": "javascript",
    "typescriptreact": "javascript"
  }
```

Can anyone give me some suggesion on how to fix it? Many Thanks.