# Prettier breaks VSCode Tailwind InteliSense or class ordering after auto line break

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, prettier, tailwind-in-js

I am using Prettier in my React app with Tailwind and twin.macro. When I write a component with multiple classes and the length of string is bigger than Prettier's `printWidth` value, the plugin break line as usual. However, sometimes the InteliSense or auto class ordering `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` stop working.

I have f.e. this component

```
const ControlsButton = tw(Button)`aspect-auto w-full justify-start gap-3 rounded-none border-gray border-b py-4 px-8 last:border-0 md:aspect-square md:w-10 md:justify-center md:rounded-full md:border-0 md:p-0`
```

When I save, the formatter do it's job and code looks like this

```
const ControlsButton = tw(
    Button
)`aspect-auto w-full justify-start gap-3 rounded-none border-gray border-b py-4 px-8 last:border-0 md:aspect-square md:w-10 md:justify-center md:rounded-full md:border-0 md:p-0`
```

That's the point, when intelisense or class ordering stop working.

I found out, that when I manually press Enter to break a line, plugins are still working.

```
const ControlsButton = tw(Button)`aspect-auto w-full justify-start gap-3 rounded-none 
    border-gray border-b py-4 px-8 last:border-0 md:aspect-square .................. md:p-0`
```

But after file save, the Prettier formatter do it's work again and the result is again

```
const ControlsButton = tw(
    Button
)`aspect-auto w-full justify-start gap-3 rounded-none border-gray border-b py-4 px-8 last:border-0 md:aspect-square md:w-10 md:justify-center md:rounded-full md:border-0 md:p-0`
```

I know, that I can use `// prettier-ignore` to prevent line breaking, but it's a quite uncomfortable.

So tried to add some configuration to my VSCode settings.json file. (inspired from [Auto Sorting Tailwind CSS class in React Native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73918825/auto-sorting-tailwind-css-class-in-react-native-project))

```
    ...
    "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
        "tw\\(\n.*?\n\\)`([^`]*)" // tw(\nComponent\n)`...`
    ],
    ...
```

Unfortunately without any progress.

Does anyone have some suggestions or using `// prettier-ignore` with manual breaks is the only way?

Thanks

Comment: Add this comment "/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
"

Comment: This unfortunately does not working